# JTable not visible when adding with JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jscrollpane

i am working on a gui based project and i need to add a jtable in a jpanel.But i am not getting why the table is not being displayed when adding with a scrollpane.Also when adding without scrollpane,the table header is not displayed.
Thanks for any help...
Following is the code i am using..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FrmAddEditDN extends JDialog{
    JButton JBUpdate = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/save.png"));
    JButton JBReset = new JButton("Reset",new ImageIcon("images/reset.png"));
    JButton JBCancel = new JButton("Cancel",new ImageIcon("images/cancel.png"));

    JLabel JLPic1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel JLBanner = new JLabel("Please fill-up all the required fields.");

public FrmAddEditDN(boolean ADD_STATE,JFrame OwnerForm,Connection srcCN,String srcSQL){
        super(OwnerForm,true);
        cnAEDN = srcCN;
        ADDING_STATE = ADD_STATE;
        JPanel JPContainer = new JPanel();
        JPContainer.setLayout(null);
                String[] columnNames = {
                    "Sr No","Invoice No","Invoice Date","Consignee","Description","Basic Amount","Invoice Amount","Payment Received",
                "EFT Date","Payment Earlier Received","Comm. @ %","Comm.Claim @ %","Comm. Received","Date","Bank","Remarks"};
                String[][] data = {
                    {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""}
   };
                DefaultTableModel DTModel = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
                JTable table = new JTable(5,16);
                table.setBounds(15,295,screen.width-40,150);
                table.setRowHeight(30);
                table.setForeground(Color.black);
                table.setBackground(Color.white);
                JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
                header.setForeground(Color.red);
                header.setBackground(Color.green);
                table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(2);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
                JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane();
                tableContainer.setViewportView(table);

                JPContainer.add(tableContainer);

                getContentPane().add(JPContainer);
        setSize(screen.width-5,screen.height-45);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When not added to a scrollpane, you need to manually add the table header as well. This is mentioned in the `JTable` class javadoc

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass `Component` while creating a [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
JPContainer.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: Then actually what is the purpose of add() method with **JScrollPane**. I tried to use like **scrollPane.add(table)** for above case, but it did not work. when should we use add() method with JScrollPane???

Comment: @amin__ it's just inherited after parent class (Container), I guess unfortunately it's not supposed to work on JScrollPane like we expect

Comment: @Line That was like half a decade ago. Makes me reminiscent. Thanks for answering though.